# Using the same volume for two Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers, one of which provides a file that I need in another container, and I want to make the first container write that file to a volume, then have the second container access that volume and read the file.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  web_data:

services:

  build_jar:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-gradle
    volumes:
      - web_data:/workdir

  generate_html:
    depends_on:
      - build_jar
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    build: .
    volumes:
      - web_data:/workdir
```

`Dockerfile-gradle`

```
FROM gradle:latest AS builder
USER root
RUN mkdir /workspace
ADD . /workspace
RUN cd /workspace && gradle shadowJar --no-daemon
RUN mkdir /workdir
RUN cp /workspace/build/libs/datainfrastructure-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar /workdir/stat.jar
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim AS java
USER root
RUN java -jar /workdir/stat.jar
```

First of all, I assumed that having created the volume in `docker-compose.yml` I would automatically get the directory `/workdir` without having to create it manually, which seems to not be the case. So I create it using `mkdir` and I do actually get my data saved: I can go to `var/lib/docker/volumes` on my host machine and find the corresponding volume with the data the container wrote. Great.

Well, secondly, now I need to use this volume with another container, which also does not have the `workdir` directory existing already. So if I try to access `/workdir/stat.jar`, it does not exist, and if I manually create `/workdir`, it's an empty directory. How do I get the files on the volume that the first container put there? Am I missing something in either Dockerfiles or `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

When you build a Docker image, the Dockerfile has no access to Docker networking, volumes, or any other part of the Docker ecosystem.  It's not unreasonable to think of `docker build` as acting like Maven or Gradle: it produces an image that you can copy to other systems and run elsewhere, but then at build time it can't access data that will eventually be present when you run it.

Correspondingly, as a general rule, Docker images should be self-contained.  An image should usually contain its language runtime and any code or artifacts necessary to run the application; sharing code (or jar files) via volumes isn't usually a best practice.  (Of particular note, if you do this successfully, Docker will always use the old jar file in the volume, in both containers, in preference to what's built into the image.)

In this context it seems more like you're looking for a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  You can combine these two Dockerfiles together, and then `COPY` the jar file from the first image to the second one.  That results in

```sh
FROM gradle:latest AS builder
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . .
RUN gradle shadowJar --no-daemon

FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim AS java
WORKDIR /workdir
COPY --from=builder /workspace/build/libs/datainfrastructure-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar stat.jar
CMD java -jar /workdir/stat.jar
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, you can delete volume along with the no-op container that does the build:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  generate_html:
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    build: .
```

Comment: Thank you! I know about multi-stage builds, but here's the thing: I want to run the second container once in 10 minutes (I've heard this can be achieved using ofelia in docker-compose?), but I don't want to run the Gradle container because it takes forever to build a jar, so I wanted to have a way to run it once and keep the jar and then run the second container in a loop. Idk if this is even possible. So if I use multi-stage builds, I have to run Gradle too, and that's slow and also kinda unnecesary? The jar itself will always be the same.

Comment: You don't have to rebuild the image every time.  Again, by parallel to Gradle, you can just re-run the image without rebuilding it the same way you can run `java -jar ...` without rebuilding the jar file.  `docker-compose up` will use an existing image if there is one; even if you specify `--build` it will run very quickly if the source files haven't changed.

Comment: It also seems to be reasonably common for Java applications to build the jar file outside of Docker, and then `COPY` that into the image, instead of trying to build everything in Docker.  That could simplify things for you if the jar file changes rarely.

Answer (score 0):

> I assumed that having created the volume in docker-compose.yml I would automatically get the directory /workdir without having to create it manually

That is not supposed, when you declare a volume mapping for some service you only declare mapping between volume and path in the future container. Your container image should guarantee that something exists on that path.

> I need to use this volume with another container, which also does not have the workdir directory existing already

Your confusion is probably related to the fact that you expect volumes to work in build time that is not true unfortunately.